# Fail2ban actionban with cURL

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, curl, sshd, fail2ban

My Ubuntu server mail is **working**. I verified with this command below.

```
echo "Mail is working on this server." | mail -s subject <myemail@gmail.com>
```

---

In my entire `jail.local`

ex. intruder ***ip*** = `1.1.1.1`

```
[sshd]
port       = 2222
destemail  = myemail@gmail.com
sendername = fail2ban
mta        = mail
action     = %(action_mwl)s
actionban  = curl -s https://www.app.com/ssh/ban?ip=1.1.1.1
```

IP seems to get banned when ssh with ban credentials attempt failed 5 times and I also got the email, but not sure why curl is not triggering to my api.

Am I missing anything ?

---

I've tried

```
[sshd]
port       = 2222
destemail  = myemail@gmail.com
sendername = fail2ban
mta        = mail
bantime    = 1m
maxretry   = 1
action     = %(action_mwl)s
banaction  = %(curlAction)s <<<< ADDED ⭐️
```

---

**curlAction.conf**

```
[Definition]
actionstart =
actionstop = 
actioncheck = 
actionban = curl -s https://www.app.com/ssh/ban?ip=1.1.1.1
actionunban =
```